# Parskip and Space Above Enumerate List

Tags: enumerate, parskip

I have changed the value for parskip but this also affects the space between the last paragraph and the first item of the enumerate environment.

My questions are:

1. Why would parskip affect something like that?
2. How to prevent parskip from affecting it?
3. Can I prevent parskip from affecting anything else than the separation between paragraphs?

Comment: parskip is a tex primitive so affects everything that is built from a primitive tex paragraph, so lists, section headings etc, more or less any text block. Classes designed for non zero parskip, or packages such as `parskip` reset compensating lengths where needed to allow for the space from parskip

Comment: Try playing with \partopsep.  You might have to make it negative.  Oh, and \unskip\begin{enumerate}.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to add parskip to your document class parameters like this:

```
\documentclass[pdftex, a4paper, parskip]{scrartcl}
```

By doing that the intends at the beginning of a paragraph are 0 and you still have the spaces between the other elements.

Altough, I think this just works for Koma-Script classes.

Comment: Indeed, it only works for the Koma-Script classes. This is one of the reasons I mostly use these classes for my documents, though. :-)